# jQuery trigger event on element with id to run handler defined by class in an included twig template

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony, twig

When calling jQuery's trigger function by the id selector, is it possible to trigger the event handler for that element that is defined by the same element's class selector? For example, say I have this HTML:

```
<div class="my_button" id="my_button_1"></div>
```

And this jQuery

```
$('.my_button').click(function() { 
    alert("button was clicked")
});
```

I'm looking call `$('#my_button_1').trigger('click')` ... and have it trigger the above jQuery for that element in the cleanest way possible.  Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:** Based on the comments below, it's clearly not an issue with jQuery. Here's the actual code being used.

```
{% block javascripts %}
    {{ include('MyMainBundle:Event:wizard.js.twig') }}
{% endblock %}
```

Handler defined in wizard.js:

```
    $('.event_type_option').click(function() {

        alert('option clicked');
        Event.eventTypeId = $(this).attr('id').substring(11);
        customComboSelect(this, $('#event_type_text'));
    });

    $('.people_range_option').click(function() {

        alert('range clicked');
        Event.peopleRangeId = $(this).attr('id').substring(13);
        customComboSelect(this, $('#people_range_text'));
    });
```

Trying to trigger the event below this:

```
{% if event is defined %}
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#event_type_{{ event.eventType.id }}').trigger('click');
            $('#people_range_{{ event.peopleRange.id }}').trigger('click');
        });
    </script>
{% endif %}
```

Additionally, The events are successfully triggered if I try triggering them directly following the handler definitions.

Comment: Is your `click` handler inside of `$(document).ready`?

Comment: Why don't you simply try it and see what happens?

Comment: You have a syntax error. `)};` should be `});`

Comment: And yes, it works just fine because the selectors don't matter with what you're concerned about. If the `click` event was bound to an element, it doesn't matter how you select it - you can trigger the event. Here - http://jsfiddle.net/yV57x/

Comment: @j08691: I am trying it, and it isn't working, hence my question. Also, care to explain the down-vote?

Comment: What is not working? http://jsfiddle.net/wZ73a/

Comment: @Ian: The syntax error was just a typo in the question.  Also, would it matter that the blocks are each in separate $(document).ready functions?

Comment: I didn't downvote you but I'm considering it. Your question doesn't show any research effort. Here's a quick jsFiddle that shows it works. http://jsfiddle.net/DUE2n/

Comment: @RHarrington Technically, yes. The `$(document).ready` handler that **binds** the events needs to happen first. It would be helpful to have more of your code available

Comment: @Ian: I'll update my question with some more code. I simplified a good deal of it since I'm including the handler binding in a separate twig template.

Comment: I've updated my answer above.  Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked to ensure `#people_range_{{ event.peopleRange.id }}` evaluates to the ID you want?

Comment: War10ck: Yes, in that same block, I did an alert('#people_range_{{ event.peopleRange.id }} and it is correct. I also tried triggering the event directly on the class from this location to no avail.

Comment: @Ian Ok, then that is the issue.  Because my javascript block is actually inserted at the bottom of the page.  That makes sense.  If you want to make an actual answer for this, I'll accept it.

Comment: Ok, nevermind, that isn't the issue either.  I made sure the trigger came after the definition of the handlers, although both in two different document ready blocks.  I think this is causing some sort of race condition. Note. the wizard.js has a good deal of javascript defined in it, could this cause a race condition?

Comment: Bah, ok, it was the order of $(document).ready's causing the issue after all.  Thanks Ian!

Comment: @RHarrington Haha okay, no problem. I added an answer, hopefully it's a good explanation of stuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Event binding in jQuery is done as a "First In, First Out" queue (it's a little more complicated with delegated events and namespaced events, but that's not too important now).

Meaning, as events are bound to an element, they are later executed in the same order when the event is triggered.

In your case, you need to bind the `click` event handler **before** attempting to `.trigger()` it. Since the event binding and the triggering are in different `$(document).ready` handlers, the handler that binds the events needs to execute before the handler that triggers the event.

Here's an example of what happens when you try to trigger before binding: http://jsfiddle.net/yV57x/1/ - notice how no `alert` occurs (unless you actually click the element in the HTML). Flipping around the `$(document).ready` handler bindings fixes the problem.

And just as a note, your original intent is perfectly valid. If the click event was bound to an element, it doesn't matter how you select it - you can trigger the event as long as you can get it. Test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/yV57x/

Comment: Thanks for taking some time to help me think through this.  This would appear obvious to most, but it was overlooked by me because the actual definition of the binding happened first in code, but it was actually being rendered at the bottom of the page by the extended twig template. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, possible. As

`$('#my_button_1')` and  `$('.my_button')` both point's to the same element

```
$('.my_button').click(function() { 
    alert("button was clicked")
});
$('#my_button_1').trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the content on the page when you are binding the event? The document could be ready, but if you are loading dynamic content or creating content and appending it on the fly on the page, the elements may not be present when the event is trying to be bound.

My guess, based on the minimal information you've provided, is that the above is true in which case you need to create a delegated event like the following:

**For jQuery 1.7 or Higher:**
[.on() Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$(document).on('click', '.my_button', function () {
    alert("Button was clicked!");
});
```

**For jQuery 1.4.2 - 1.7:**
[.delegate() Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

```
$(document).delegate('.my_button', 'click', function () {
    alert("Button was clicked!");
});
```

**For jQuery 1.3 - 1.4.2:**
[.live() Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

```
$('.my_button').live('click', function () {
    alert("Button was clicked!");
});
```

These methods use event delegation. The element(s) do not even have to be on the page when these handlers are setup. As the content is dynamically loaded, jQuery will attach the event handlers for you automatically.

In addition it should be noted that if content, which has a handler is removed from the DOM, you should use the [.remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) or [.empty()](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) jQuery commands to prevent memory leaks as these first remove all bound events and then the elements.

**Edit**
I added reference links to all the appropriate documentation for each call. Also the last call was supposed to be `.live()` not `.on()`. That was a copy and paste error but is now fixed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The event handlers are included as part of a separate twig template, but after rendering, which should happen before document ready.  The content is not being loaded in dynamically, and I've confirmed that the event handler works if I put the trigger directly after defining it.  Not sure why it isn't working further down the page.

Comment: @RHarrington Have you viewed the console to see if you're getting any errors? You may also want to try opening up Chrome (if you have it) and in the console typing `monitorEvents(document.getElementsByClassName('my_button'), 'click');`. This will show you all the `click` events that fire for that element. This will ensure the `click` is actually firing.

Comment: I do use chrome, as I feel it has the best debugging ability.  The monitorEvents function is news to me though, thanks!

Comment: @RHarrington I would definitely agree with you 100% on the debugging ability. Chrome is amazing for that. No problem though buddy. Just found out about that command myself two days ago. It works like a charm for testing events. Let me know what kind of feedback you get (i.e. if the event fires or doesn't) and I'll try to help you some more from there.

Comment: That command just displays "undefined." But if I type the document.getElementsByClassName part, it outputs all the divs in the console.

Comment: @RHarrington That's correct it should display undefined. It doesn't return anything. Now leave the console open and click the button. If the handler bound correctly you'll see a similar event the the following: `click 
MouseEvent {dataTransfer: null, toElement: body.question-page, fromElement: null, y: 519, x: 224…}` appear in the console for every time you click the button.

Comment: I click the button, but nothing is displayed in the console.  But the alert from within the handler is displayed.

Comment: hmm...you may want to try monitoring the events all the way up the document level like so `monitorEvents(document, 'click');`. Not sure why it wouldn't show. The alert is good though right, isn't that what you wanted to show? As a side not to stop the monitoring do `unmonitorEvents(document);` or whatever the respective selector is.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, this is how it works.

The selector part selects elements `$('.my_button')`. Those elements get assigned an `onclick` handler:

```
.click(function() { 
    alert("button was clicked")
)};
```

Then `$('#my_button_1').trigger('click')` should give you an alert.

---

The 'cleanest' way to call event handler programmatically is (in my opinion) to not use `trigger`. The DOM is view, treat it as a view. If you're going to do things in your controller keep them in the controller.